# Kurtosis t-distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $T$ have a t-distribution with $r> 4$  degrees of freedom. Determine the kurtosis of $T.$

We use the expression 
$$E(T^k )=E(W^k )(2^{-k/2}  Γ(r/2-k/2))/(Γ(r/2) r^{-k/2} )$$
to determine the kurtosis of $T.$

And the kurtosis is $E[(x-μ)^4 ]/σ^4$

how can we connect the two?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), table at top right gives the kurtosis of a t distribution. Your work may be simplified by noticing that the mean of $\mathsf{T}(\text{df} = r) = 0, r > 4.$

Comment: I have tried editing your Question so it is easier to read. But you still need to tell us what $W, k,$ and $x$ are.